# spl_autoload fails when script ran from command line

Tags: php

I know this has to do with the path not being quite right but it has me baffled. I can run my script with no problems at all from the browser but when I do to the exact same spot from a shell, spl_autoload complains and dies:

> Fatal error:  spl_autoload(): Class db
>   could not be loaded in...

I am using the absolute path from the root directory, echoed to screen and pasted it into a shell and verified that it is good. Please... what am I missing??

Comment: Could you provide a pertinent snippet of the code which is failing?

Comment: Run `php -i` from command line and check if it's using the same `php.ini` as web-server

Comment: also try running that script as root from the shell (if it's not too risky). If it works then it might be a permission problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `__DIR__` constant to locate the files, CLI PHP doesn't uses the same working dir.

Use something like this:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/libraries/' . $class . '.php');
}
```

Comment: Alix, thanks for helping. I have never used the __DIR__ constant and tried to echo the result but only got back '__DIR__. I used echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; instead and it gave me the exact path where my script resides. Is this what you wanted to see?

Comment: `__DIR__` is only available since PHP 5.3.0, use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can usually grab your root directory for the project with something along the lines of :

```
// The file that defines this is 2 directories below root, hence the ../ changes.
define('PATH_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../'));
```

Once you have your root path you can modify your include path, using set_include_path. (remember to include get_include_path when you set it otherwise you'll lose the defaults)

once thats sorted, just setup your autoloader assuming against the root dir and you should be fine, since its a bit more concrete than relying on relative paths which can change according to the working dir.